# custom expression in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a web security application with Java, Spring and Mybatis. I used Rest controllers to provide data to front end. On backend side, I secured Rest controllers with:

```
<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"
    metadata-source-ref="customMetadataSource" />

<beans:bean id="customMetadataSource"
    class="org.dummy.CustomMetadataSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry
                key="#{T(org.dummy.RoleAuthenticatedUser)}"
                value="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER')" />                                   
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

The annotation @RoleAuthenticatedUser is quite simple:

```
 @java.lang.annotation.Target(value={java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD,java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE})
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(value=java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@java.lang.annotation.Inherited
@java.lang.annotation.Documented
public @interface RoleAuthenticatedUser {

}
```

When I want to securize a REST web service I simply decorate it with this annotation.

```
@RoleAuthenticatedUser
@Transactional
@Benchmark  
@GetMapping(value = RICHIESTA_ABILITAZIONE_DOCUMENTI_URL, headers = "Accept="
        + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RichiestaAccesso> impostaAbilitazioneDocumenti(@AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUser user,  @PathVariable("richiestaAccesso") String idRichiestaAccesso, @PathVariable("codiceFiscale") String codiceFiscale, @PathVariable("abilita")  boolean abilitazioneDocumenti) {           
    return ...;
}

public interface JwtUser extends UserIdentity {

    long getLastAccessedTime();

    long getDurationTime();

    String getUid();

    void touched();

    boolean isValid();

    List<ProfiloUtente> getProfiles();

}
```

I defined a `JwtUser` as Principal, so when I call the `Authentication.getPrincipal` I receive an `JwtUser` object.

It works perfectly, without any problem. I want to add another annotation that check that the user (JwtUser) has at least 2 profiles (I need to check the `getProfiles` list). To accomplish this task I extends the configuration in the following way:

```
<beans:bean id="customMetadataSource"
    class="it.insiel.stt.interrogazioni.web.security.CustomMetadataSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry
                key="#{T(org.dummy.RoleAuthenticatedUser)}"
                value="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER')" />                   
                <beans:entry
                key="#{T(org.dummy.RoleProfiledUser)}"
                value="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER') and authentication.principal.profiles.size>1" />                  
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

As you can notice, I simply add another annotation, named @RoleProfiledUser and I associated it to the following expression:

```
hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER') and authentication.principal.profiles.size>1
```

I associated it to a REST controller but it does not work. What is the mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the error. Just add parenthesis and all works!

```
hasRole('ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER') and authentication.principal.profiles.size()>1
```